# Macro Vba - IE...Click, Not working button

Tags: vba, asp, internet-explorer, macro, click

Não estou conseguindo clicar em um botão que gera um relatório em Excel(depois ele abre aquela abinha de "Download de arquivo" "Desejar salvar? Abrir? Cancelar?, mas essa parte é tranquilo, eu acho, se não for me avisem e se já tiverem a solução...).

Problema é tentei várias formas:

```
IE.Document.getElementById("download_token_value").removeAttribute("onClick") 'FAILED
IE.Document.getElementById("download_token_value").setAttribute "onClick", "return true" 'FAILED
IE.Document.getElementsByName("DownloadToken").Item.onclick 'FAILED

For Each Button In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("DownloadToken") 'FAILED
    Button.Click
Next
    IE.Document.getElementById("download_token_value").submit 'FAILED
    IE.Document.getElementById("download_token_value").Click 'FAILED
    IE.Document.all("download_token_value").Click 'FAILED
    IE.Document.getElementById("download_token_value").Click 'FAILED
    IE.Document.getElementsByName("DownloadToken").Item.Click 'FAILED
```

Nenhum desses funcionou, e eu troquei várias vezes as propriedades como disse:

```
  </ul>
</div>

<form action="/RptManifestoStatus/Index" method="post"><input id="download_token_value" name="DownloadToken" type="hidden" value="" />
<div class ="toolbar">
  <div class ="toolbarBorder">
    <div class="toolbarItem">
      <input class="btExportarExcel" src="/Content/images/pix.gif" style="vertical-align: bottom; border:0;" type="image" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>    
<div class="boxContent">
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
```

Outra observação, todos os métodos, usando o "Click" funcionam, o código roda, mas... não abre a aba de download de arquivo, como se não clicasse no botão, ou seja, ele acha o objeto/botão, só não executa o script eu acho.
É o último passo, praticamente pra essa macro, o processo vai ficar 100% automático com isso.

Answer (score 0):

No seu HTML não vejo nenhum botão chamado `download_token_value` apenas um `input` do tipo `hidden` que não possui nenhum evento `click` associado ao mesmo, e nem deveria, pois é um elemento escondido na página.

Se o seu campo, segundo o que estou vendo, possui a URL para download, porque não baixá-lo diretamente ao invés de mandar para outra janela?

Assim:

```
'Pode ser Public ou Private, depende do seu projeto
Private Function BaixarArquivo(strURL As String, strCaminhoArquivo As String, enumOpcoesGravacao As SaveOptionsEnum) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrHandle

    Dim objStream As New ADODB.Stream
    Dim objWinHttpReq As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

    'Acessa a URL via GET de maneira síncrona
    objWinHttpReq.Open "GET", strURL, False
    objWinHttpReq.send

    With objStream
        If objWinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
            .Open
            .Type = adTypeBinary
            .Write objWinHttpReq.responseBody
            .SaveToFile strCaminhoArquivo, enumOpcoesGravacao
            .Close
        End If
    End With

    Set objStream = Nothing
    Set objWinHttpReq = Nothing
ErrHandle:
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        BaixarArquivo = True
    Else
        Debug.Print "Erro número:" & Err.Number & " | " & Err.Description
        Err.Clear
        BaixarArquivo = False
    End If
End Function
```

E chamar a função, por exemplo, pra baixar um pdf na pasta `C:\`:

```
If BaixarArquivo(IE.Document.getElementById("download_token_value").Value, "C:\Arquivo.pdf", adSaveCreateOverWrite) Then
    Msgbox "Download concluído"
End If
```

Não esqueça de ir em **Ferramentas** > **Referências** e selecionar os itens:

- `Microsoft WinHTTP Services`
- `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 library`